# Закрасить всю строку в Excel

Tags: c#, excel, color, background

Открываю в c# Excel, туда записываю данные в соответствующие строки и столбцы, необходимо по условию выделить строчку каким-то цветом, как это можно сделать? Нашел лишь закраску отдельных ячеек на англ. форуме, но это не то.
Грубо говоря, есть

```
ws.Cells[lastRow + i, 2].Value2 = resData.TF;
```

И если resData.TF > 0, то соответствующую строку `lastRow + i` я закрашиваю зеленым, в обратном случае красным.

Comment: `ws.Cells[lastRow + i, 2].EntireRow.Color = IIF(resData.TF > 0, vbGreen, vbRed)`

Comment: @Akina спасибо, странно, перепробовал вариантом 5-6 и не работало, сейчас всё получилось)

Comment: Да, если надо закрасить фон, а не символы - используйте `EntireRow.Interior.Color`.

Comment: Не знаю, сработает ли в *C#* -  в *VBA* можно указывать строку, не задействуя ячейку: *Rows(lastRow + i).Interior.Color*

Answer (score 2):

Можно строки красить так:

```
var iRow = 1; //номер строки
ws.Rows[$"{iRow}:{iRow}"].Interior.Color = Color.Red;
```